# Migrating a live WordPress website to a Local Server: why some elements of the website are missing?

Tags: php, migration, localhost

After many many hours (days, actually) trying to migrate a live WordPress website to a local server, I'm finally getting things to work. One really annoying thing was that some elements of the website were missing, and after many more hours I found out that the culprit was some missing `php` in the `<?php` tag. If I add the `php`, the missing element misteriously reappears on the page. The files I edited was php files inside the `/themes` folder.

Is this normal or am I missing something? How to properly resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the what I thought to be incomplete tags was actually just the [short form](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) of the delimiter (as you can notice, I'm not very familiar with PHP and WordPress).

Instead of editing every single file and appending `php` to every `<?` tag, the solution could not be easier:

```
Apache > PHP > PHP Settings > short open tag
```

**Boom**.

*sigh*